# Sampling Weights with latent profile analysis package

Tags: sampling, latent-variable, latent-class, jackknife

Is there a package for latent profile analysis in R that can accommodate sampling weights?  I am using tidyLPA and would prefer to use this package if anyone has knowledge about how methods such as jackknife could be used in tidyLPA.

Comment: You can use sampling design specification for latent class analysis in Stata. Just saying.

Comment: Thanks I guess.

Comment: If you can disassemble `tidyLPA` (I have never worked with it) and figure out if it produces a likelihood and its derivatives, you can feed these to `survey::svymle()` http://search.r-project.org/library/survey/html/svymle.html.